# Wireshark UDP packet filter

Tags: networking, udp, wireshark

I want to capture all UDP packets sent from port 7777 on my local machine, but I am not sure what capture filter to use. This does not seems to be correct, any idea?

udp and host xxx.xxx.x.xx and src port 7777

Comment: I think `udp.srcport == 7777` is part of what you're looking for.

Comment: How to capture both source and destination on that port?

Answer (score 0):

This filter seems correct. Make sure you have sufficient permissions for capturing

Answer (score 0):

You should add the port in Preferences section in wire-shark